# tsconfig and paths in angular project

Tags: angular

I created Angular application. I'm trying to configure tsconfig and create shortcut-path for my interfaces. I edited tsconfig.app.json,
added baseUrl and paths:

```
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
"types": [],
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@models/*": ["./app/modules/models/*"]
}
```

...but I'm still getting error:

```
ERROR in src/app/modules/atoms/small-table/small-table.component.ts:3:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find 
module '@models'.

3 import { IIncome } from '@models'
```

file structure:
[image]

Does somebody know why it not working? How to fix it?

Comment: add this in the paths too: `"@models": ["./app/modules/models"]`

Comment: duplicate line?

Comment: No, use both, one with asterisk and one without and in VS Code execute Restart TS Server from the commands

Comment: used, not worked :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you're seeing this in VSCode, the issue is probably `baseUrl`**

Whether you're using tsconfig.json or tsconfig.app.json, you need to ensure that the `baseUrl` property inside `compileOptions` is configured properly. Wherever you're setting up your `path` options with the `@` wildcard, ensure your `baseUrl` points to the right base directory.

The default is:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
}
```

Depending on your application's structure, change this to:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    ...
}
```

or to:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    ...
}
```

It looks like in your case, you should use `src` like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    ...

    "paths": {
      "@models/*": ["app/modules/models/*"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

index exports aren't well supported by typescript. just do your import like this:

```
import { IIncome } from '@models/index'
```

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

The first problem can be, according to your code snippet, that your `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` placed in one folder. But according to ng initial folder structure - `tsconfig.app.json` placed in the src folder, `tsconfig.json` - placed in the root. Please, pay attention and check it out.

The second thing, if you use barrel files, you need to add additional path mapping.

Here the example how it should look like:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@models": [
        "app/modules/models/index"
      ],
      "@models/*": [
        "app/modules/models/*"
      ],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `"extends": "./tsconfig.json"`?

Most probably it should be with `../` like so: `"extends": "../tsconfig.json"` , unless you have 2 tsconfig files next to each other, which is unusual. When application is generated via `ng new` you should have 1 tsconfig on the root level and 2 inside src folder: `tsconfig.json` , `src/tsconfig.app.json` and `src/tsconfig.spec.json`